# How can I use sed to find the lines that start with "X", then find and replace inside this line using Perl?

Tags: perl, sed

In a bash script I've used this method successfully many times:

```
sed -i '/^drop/s/(msg:"/(msg:"drop - /' /file
```

I think for perl a simple find and replace with sed is this:

```
s/^alert/drop/;
```

How can I replicate the first line in perl to find a line that starts with `drop` then find inside this line `msg: "` and replace it with `msg: "drop -` ?

I've tried this with no success.

```
s/^drop/ s/(msg:\"/(msg:\"drop - /;
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is the "perl" doing in your question? Do you want to use `sed`, `perl`, or both?

Comment: @reinierpost, I'm making changes to a perl script called `pulledpork` and needed help using sed in this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s/^(drop.*msg:")/${1}drop - /;
```

In more complex cases (e.g. if you want to add `/g`), you might want something that follows the following pattern:

```
/^drop/ && s/(msg:")/${1}drop - /;
```

Or if you have Perl 5.10+,

```
s/^drop.*msg:"\K/drop - /;

/^drop/ && s/msg:"\K/drop - /;
```

Comment: @Miller, Non-greediness used as anything but an optimization is non-greediness misused. There's no way to know it would be more efficient with non-greediness, so I took it out. Thanks for removing the erroneous `^`, though. No idea how that got there.

Comment: Oh, that change wasn't about efficiency.  It was about covering for edge cases: `msg:"msg:"`.  I doubt that case would come up, but I like it when my two regex suggestion is functionally equivalent to my single combined regex suggestion.  With greedy matching they are subtly different.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i  -pe '/^drop/ && s/\(msg:"/\(msg:"drop - /' /file
```

test it first without "in place" file modification (changed content printed to stdout):

```
perl -pe '/^drop/ && s/\(msg:"/\(msg:"drop - /' /file
```

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe not ideal - but you could look at using groups with the regex to grab the text between "drop" and "msg", and insert said text into the replacement string.

```
$value =~ s/^drop(.*)msg: \"/drop$1msg: "drop -/g;
```